# Ubuntu (VM) showing two different workspace when connected to external screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, workspaces, virtualization

I'm new to ubuntu and have a very strange issue. 
I'm running ubuntu as a Hyper V machine from windows 8.1 and connecting through xRDP. When i'm at work, I use an external monitor. When i RDP to the machine without the external screen connected I get a different workspace.

Another example: If I have chrome open in the non-external-monitor workspace, then when i'm connected to the monitor I can't open chrome (Well, it opens, but not in the workspace i'm seeing)
The thing is, I can't find that other workspace anywhere!

Please, this is so weird!! Appreciate any wisdom on this strange case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press the windows button to open Dash. Search for Displays, and open it. You should find everything you need right there, but for a quick fix, select the checkbox `Mirror displays` on the right side.

Most likely, the windows are considered to be side by side. Moving the mouse pointer out of the screen towards left or right should get you to the other workspace. You can click and drag windows to choose what to display on each screen.

Comment: Thanks for that. I would like to test your answer but i've got an unrelated bug that doesn't allow me to access my Display configurations. It's a known bug, so not much I can do about it.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/954739. I'll accept the answer though